# Covariate adjustment for "mediated" reverse causality

Tags: causality, dag, causal-diagram, reverse-causality, backdoor-path

I have made the following DAG in dagitty.net:

[image]

DAGitty says "The total effect cannot be estimated by covariate adjustment".

I don't understand why I can't close the backdoor path by controlling for U.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your graph is not a DAG because there is a cycle, so you're outside the model class.

Comment: This answer is totally correct, but sometimes a fix can be to view the problem like a time series, where the arrows flow X_t --> Y_t --> U_t+1 --> X_t+1.... This does not have a cycle and so is easier to work with. Of course, that may or may not be a reasonable model for your use case.